# Assign integer value to a variable in prolog?

Tags: variables, prolog

I'm trying to assign a value integer to varible (i need for university  homework) and I'm doing this:

```
updateSequenceOfSteps( PrevLocs, [H|T], FS ) :-
    **Lies := 0,**
    nth0(0, H, X),
    nth0(1, H, Y),
    nth0(2, H, S),
    nth0(3, H, M),
    write([X,Y,S,M]),
    updatePosBarcenasLocs( PrevLocs, X, Y, S, M, Lies,NextLocs ),
    updateSequenceOfSteps( NextLocs, T, FS ).
```

I need Lies becomes 0. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the Prolog documentation? `:=` isn't a valid operator in Prolog. That's a Pascal assignment statement. Look up the Prolog unification operator.

Comment: You use Lies only in one place, Y U No just write 0 there?

Comment: I use it in more places. This is a small piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the line between ** for  "Lies is 0".

Thanks to all.